# Multiplying an integer by another integer certain number of times in apple script

Tags: applescript

I was recently trying to multiply two integers several number of times in apple script, but didn't manage to do it. I was trying to use all kinds of repeat loops, but the integers only multiply one time and than nothing happens. My code looks like this.

```
display dialog "Enter the first number here" default answer ""
set firstnumber to text returned of result
display dialog "Enter the second number." default answer ""
set secondnumber to text returned of result
display dialog "How many times numbers should be multiplied?" default answer ""
set multiplier to text returned of result
repeat multiplier times
    set finalresult to firstnumber * secondnumber
end repeat
display dialog finalresult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given script multiplies the first number by the second number over and over. Instead, you *want* it to iterate: multiply the *result of the previous multiplication* by the second number. You do that like so:

```
display dialog "Enter the first number here" default answer ""
set firstnumber to text returned of result
display dialog "Enter the second number." default answer ""
set secondnumber to text returned of result
display dialog "How many times numbers should be multiplied?" default answer ""
set multiplier to text returned of result
-- set the output variable to the first number
set finalresult to firstnumber
repeat multiplier times
    -- repeatedly multiply the output variable by the second number,
    -- storing it back in the output variable
    set finalresult to finalresult * secondnumber
end repeat
display dialog finalresult
```

Answer (score 0):

A more direct approach negates the need for a repeat loop by observing that repeatedly multiplying some constant by another  times, i.e.:

⓵    ×  ×  ×  × … ×

(where  occurs in  consecutive multiplications) is identical to and can be expressed as:

⓶    × *ⁿ*

is your starting value, which can be referred to as a *coefficient*.   is the *base* (of exponentiation), which is the the rate of exponential increase of our starting coefficient.   is the *exponent* (or *power*) that determines how many orders of magnitude  will be increased by.

So you can replace the string of ’s from ⓵—which one would be inclined to calculate iteratively by way of a repeat loop—with the single binary operation of exponentiation, i.e. *ⁿ*, for which most programming languages have a designated operator.  In AppleScript, it’s `^`.

```
set coeff to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter the coefficient, i.e. a starting value")
set base to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter the base of exponentiation")
set pow to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter the power of exponentiation")

return coeff * (base ^ pow)
```